# How to split a node with even number of keys in B+ tree

Tags: indexing, data-structures, tree, b-tree

I'm implementing a B+tree as explained in *Fundamentals of Database Systems* book
What confused me is this case

let's say we have a b+-tree with the following:
`Order=4
Max keys=3
keys to be inserted: 2,4,7,10,17`

following the algorithm, I know that when a nodes becomes **full** we **split**
Now, my solution is:

```
insert 2  4  7 (no problem)
insert 10 (node is full > split)
```

here what confused me shall we split into two having 4 as the root node
OR 7 as root node?

both are middle! I found people having different solutions, so what is right?